# How to format highlighted text

Tags: vba

I am using macro in ms-word 2007

I have to find double letter. for eg: PP in apple ,cc & ss in access (from "aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh,ii,jj,kk,ll,mm,nn,oo,pp,qq,rr,ss,tt,uu,vv,ww,xx,yy,zz") 
and format the above double letter Font into scale - 75% ,spacing - expanded ,By - 0.5pt

I have vb code to highlight double letter but I do not have code to select & format the above double letter Font into scale - 75% ,spacing - expanded ,By - 0.5pt

```
Sub Macro_test()
'
' Macro_alphabet Macro
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, Rng As Range, i As Long
StrFnd = "aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh,ii,jj,kk,ll,mm,nn,oo,pp,qq,rr,ss,tt,uu,vv,ww,xx,yy,zz"
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
  Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With Rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .text = Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
  End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use macro-recorder - that will give you almost all the answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PeterL mentioned, you can just record a macro.

Here is what it looks like

```
        With Selection.Font
            .Spacing = 0.5
            .Scaling = 75
        End With
```

you may have to modify ths slightly to be "with rng.font" or similar to match your selection method.

Comment: Mr PeterL can you provide a single VB script which can find double letters in a document and modify into scale - 75% ,spacing - expanded ,By - 0.5pt                                                                            Advance Thanks